# SP2013 Azure Information Protection (or IRM) integration

Tags: 2013, azure, irm

I'm looking to find a way to label documents in SharePoint 2013 with Microsoft AIP.
Looking around online, I can't find anything related to this specific use case:

Open document form page in SharePoint (not the document itself) and select a field value that will label the document.

**OR**

Label a document through webservices.

From my search this doesn't seem possible, but still, it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint on-prem does not have AIP automatic labeling capabilities. You would need to label the documents manually or use the AIP scanner.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/deploy-aip-scanner

Comment: And by "manually" you mean through office apps, right? No way to do it manually through SharePoint On-prem interface?

Comment: No, that is what the AIP scanner is for so you don't have to do this manually.